# Two groups of people- will they meet, ever?

Tags: riddle, knowledge

A man of war

A ball of carbon without pastor nor full hurricane

A spider

One whose strength is in the same area as Veralidaine Sarrasri

A toy maker of sorts,

A Jason-type

And one whose pallor is that of Briar Moss' magic.

---

A man whose names vary from Charles to James to Patrick,

Someone who is Nail Product

He that appears as the half dead person, one soul in two bodies

El verano, though quite a bit more dangerous

An icy animal

And one who cries naught forevermore

Comment: Tamora Pierce is a very narrow topic.

Comment: Yeah... Well... I was reading and it just fits well

Comment: @ADG I tagged trivia for that reason

Comment: Hang on ... what about Tamora Pierce?

Comment: Hmmmm?  Oh, nothing really...  Book references are what you see most with me.  Or movie references.  Those too.

Comment: There's one obvious Patrick Stewart reference, thats all I see

Comment: Who?  Wait, I'll go do a bit of research.

Comment: Warning, HP reference

Comment: Where's Tamora Pierce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably didn't get everything right but I think I'm on the right track:

### The first group

> Avengers characters

A man of war

> Captain America

A ball of carbon without pastor nor full hurricane

> Bucky Barnes (Buck = Buckminsterfullerene - minister - full - irene)

A spider

> Black Widow

One whose strength is in the same area as Veralidaine Sarrasri

> Hawkeye (bow user: credit Gracelyn)

A toy maker of sorts,

> Iron Man (invents all sorts of toys/gadgets)

A Jason-type

> Thor (comes from mythology like Jason/Argonauts)

And one whose pallor is that of Briar Moss' magic.

> Hulk (green skin)

### The second group

> Xmen characters

A man whose names vary from Charles to James to Patrick,

> Professor X (Charles Xavier, James McAvoy, Patrick Stewart)

Someone who is Nail Product

> Magneto (Erik Lehnsherr was Polish in the movie)

He that appears as the half dead person, one soul in two bodies

> Banshee (credit: Gracelyn - looks a lot like Fred and George in the movies, one of which died in the battle of Hogwarts.)

El verano, though quite a bit more dangerous

> Havoc aka Alex Summers (verano = summer)

An icy animal

> Beast (icy = blue, beast = animal)

And one who cries naught forevermore

> Raven (aka Mystique) ("Quoth the Raven nevermore")

### Finally

> There's rumors of an X-men Avengers crossover movie, so maybe.

Comment: Aww... You're on the right track, but didn't interpret the clues correctly.  +1 for your efforts.

Comment: @AJL How far off am I?  Are the groups at all correct?  I could come up with lots of different answers for the first set depending on which group I thought they belonged to.

Comment: Well, one group is correct, however only one person from that group is correct(and no others from any group)

Comment: Better in the second group.  The first is still way off

Comment: 3 right in the same category.  I think you think too highly of my comics knowledge.  Only DC characters I know are Batman, Superman etc.  Also, part of one which you put multiple answers for is right.

Comment: Only a couple wrong.  One in the first group, and 3 wrong in the second.  You may want to change the last category(whether they'll meet).

Comment: Same ones wrong.  Your edits didn't help much.  Ice as in color.  Helpful?

Comment: @AJL Yeah I'm guessing wildly now.  Maybe someone else can pitch in and help me out.

Comment: Maybe Gracelyn, from what I've seen of one certain riddle.

Comment: Daine's clue is still incorrect, and aren't there other Summers'?  At least in the movie....  Half dead may be a bit hard.  Think DH, HP and maybe take a look on Fanfiction websites for the abbreviations...

Comment: Ok I edited to add Gracelyn's answers.

Answer (score 2):

My edits to JS1's answer

> I think that the Daine clue means Hawkeye from the Avengers. And the Half dead clue refers to the Banshee, who looks a lot like Fred and George in the movies, one of which died in the battle of Hogwarts.

Comment: Good job.  +1, but I'll give the best andswer to JS1.  Sorry..

Comment: Thanks for the help!  I combined your answers into mine for people to see.